# How to remove all nontext nodes from the beginning of the contents of a div?

Tags: jquery, html, removing-whitespace

How can I remove the NonText Nodes(BR,empty `<p>` tags, nbsp) from the html of a div but only those which occur before the first text node appears. Just like stripping leading white space from a normal string of characters, but here to remove leading whitespace from the HTML string.

I have tried using Regular Expressions, but often problems occur in this approach. I would like to do it using `NodeType` and JQuery. If anyone has any example, please share.

Thanks!

`UPDATE:`

Take the following DIV:-

```
<div id="foo">
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>
                </p>
                <p>
                    &nbsp;
                </p>
                <br/>
                <p>
                    this is a test</p>
                <p>
                    &nbsp;
                </p>
                <br />
                <br>
                <p>
                    this is a fast test
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When passing "foo" to the whitespace removal function, it should become like following:-

```
<div id="foo">
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    this is a test</p>
                <p>
                    &nbsp;
                </p>
                <br />
                <br>
                <p>
                    this is a fast test
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
var $contents = $('#foo').contents();
var stopFiltering = false;

$contents.filter(function() {
    var isEmpty = $.trim($(this).text()) == '' ||
                  this.tagName == "BR";
    var shouldFilter = !stopFiltering && isEmpty;
    stopFiltering = stopFiltering || !isEmpty;
    return shouldFilter;
}).remove();
```

This is an adaptation of the `filter` function. Each element (including text nodes) is tested for "emptiness" (`isEmpty`). After the first non-empty node is seen `shouldFiltering` is set to false, and this way the filtering condition expresses your requirements: select empty nodes and elements before the first non-empty one.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Z974Z/8/)**.

**Update:** [Recursive solution is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z974Z/14/). It simply packages the above into a function `TrimElements` and recurses into all children of the target element before processing the target element itself.

Comment: But this will remove those tags from everywhere in the content of DIV, even those which appear after the actual text has started in the DIV.

Comment: @PuneetDudeja: Updated the answer, should now work as you require.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have posted my own answer, but I saw your modified answer after I just posted my one.

Comment: This is not working for me, because it handles only the immediate children and not the inner ones. I have tried using recursion to modify it, but not getting it done. Also, it does not handle nbsp tags. Can you please modify it to use recursion and handle the inner ones also ? The one I have tried is in my update answer below.

Comment: @PuneetDudeja: Please amend the question or post a JSfiddle with your input and the expected output, because it's not totally clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @PuneetDudeja: And I the answer.

Comment: This only works on jsfiddle but not actually on broswer. Please see it here: http://puneetdudeja.com/test1.html

Comment: @PuneetDudeja: Of course it doesn't work because you are not loading jQuery successfully. Please debug these issues yourself.

Comment: No, jquery is being loaded properly. It is working on chrome, but not on IE8. This I have seen just now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3695/discussion-between-puneet-dudeja-and-jon)